# Android- How to display an external video feed

Tags: java, android

I have made a robot that is controlled with my Asus tablet (TF300T). I have written the control app using MIT app inventor which communicates over bluetooth. What id like to do is mount some kind of video camera (either a stock wireless web cam, or a specialist camera from somewhere like sparkfun) onto the robot and then modify the control app to display the video feed. I understand that I will have to ditch app inventor to do this and write using the SDK directly and that is fine, but I would like to know if the concept is possible and if so could you kindly point me to some resources that document this ?

all help appreciated.

Comment: There are apps on the market for viewing some types of ip webcams, as for doing it yourself the typical mjpeg format is not inherently supported by android, but it should not be too hard to parse as a series of somewhat jpeg-like images.